# ctime Error making me unable to close the source file tab

Tags: c, syntax-error, out-of-memory, ctime

I am attempting to use ctime in my .c source file code, but for some reason ctime is getting several syntax errors. Additionally, I cannot even close Visual Studios or the ctime tab at all because I keep getting an error saying "The operation cannot be completed. Not enough storage is available to complete this operation". Also, when I attempt to compile my code again I am taken to save a file, but the save button does not work at all. I am essentially stuck having my VS window up with no way to remove ctime to try something else. What should I do to deal with this issue?

EDIT: This is the file attempting to save even when I switch to time.h

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ctime.*

ctime syntax:

```
// ctime standard header
#pragma once
#ifndef _CTIME_
#define _CTIME_
#include <yvals.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifndef RC_INVOKED
_STD_BEGIN
using _CSTD clock_t; using _CSTD size_t;
using _CSTD time_t; using _CSTD tm;
using _CSTD asctime; using _CSTD clock; using _CSTD ctime;
using _CSTD difftime; using _CSTD gmtime; using _CSTD localtime;
using _CSTD mktime; using _CSTD strftime; using _CSTD time;
_STD_END
#endif /* RC_INVOKED */
#endif /* _CTIME_ */

/*
* Copyright (c) by P.J. Plauger. All rights reserved.
* Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
V6.50:0009 */
```

Errors:

-identifier "namespace" is undefined   Line 9

-PCH warning: header stop needs to be at global scope. An IntelliSense PCH file was not generated   Line 17

-syntax error: identifier 'std'   Line 9

-syntax error: ';'   Line 9

-found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)   Line 9

-syntax error: '}'   Line 15

-unexpected end-of-file found (My original .c file)   Line 75 (I only have 74 lines)

My current code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h> //Edited from #include <ctime>

void dealCard(char hand[][5]);

//Global variables
char cards[5][14] =
{
    { 'A', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'K', 'Q', 'J' },
    { 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C' },
    { 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D' },
    { 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H' },
    { 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S' }
};
char p1Hand[2][5] =
{
    { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL },
    { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL }
};
char p2Hand[2][5] =
{
    { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL },
    { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL }
};

char p1Name[15], p2Name[15];

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    printf("-------------\n    POKER\n-------------\n\n[CHARACTERS AFTER A SPACE WILL BE IGNORED]\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter player 1's name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", &p1Name);
    printf("%s", p1Name);
    getchar();


    return 0;
}

void dealCard(char hand[][5])
{
    int x, y;
    bool added = false;
reset:
    //Chooses a random card from the deck
    x = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    y = rand() % 14;

    //Adds the card to the hand
    if (cards[x][y] != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; added == false; i++)
        {
            if (hand[0][i] == NULL)
            {
                added = true;
                hand[0][i] = cards[0][y];
                hand[1][i] = cards[x][y];
                cards[x][y] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        goto reset;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `cards` array has an extra `,`.

Comment: You can't use `namespace` in c, and you are apparently trying to. Why?

Comment: `#include <ctime>`  --> `#include <time.h>` Header files without ".h" are usually C++ header files.

Comment: Ok so I switched to time.h, but the problem with ctime unable to close still persists

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, just [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Don't edit your question.